# Black border on Canvas HTML 5

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm putting this canvas as the background of my website but for some reason it have a black border that I don't want, I'lve tried to take it off with css and javascript with nothing seems to work.

Also, if you click on the canvas/background you create a water ripple, but the cursor its a little off and I want it to create the ripple under it.

EDIT: Sorry, I'm new here, here's a live version so you can look into the code "water.js"

http://buddhatest.comyr.com

http://buddhatest.comyr.com/water.js

Comment: You need to post your code in your question.

Comment: A screenshot might be helpful as well to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Provide a sample of what you have so far please.

Comment: Please look http://buddhatest.comyr.com

Comment: Interestingly, the border is actually only 1px (the canvas is scaled a lot), and it looks like the code is skipping those border pixels in the process() function. For example, i starts at width+1 (skipping the first row) and after each row, i += 2, skipping the first and last pixels in the row. This seems very deliberate.

Comment: @gengkev the domain doesn't seem to load on my client. I've checked my DNS settings and that's not the problem. How'd you get it to work?

Comment: i...? that's very interesting; all i did was click on the link

Comment: Yeah, for some reason the website gets crazy if you use it on Safari, I really don't know why. Also, there's a possible alternative for creating this background without using canvas?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts (amusingly the source code is available [on another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119121/how-to-use-class-instead-of-background-image-in-javascript))

Comment: @Josef well, that might be difficult... the easiest solution is probably to try to figure out how to resize the canvas with JavaScript in proportion with the window size, and given the image size (320x240)

Comment: @gengkev so the problem is because of the canvas size? How about the cursos thing?

Comment: @Josef no, the problem is that the code was probably designed to have a black border, which is why it exists; and there's not really any _good_ way to fix that. don't know about the cursor

Comment: @gengkev well i just tested it with a different background size and it seems that you can't delete it but you can make it thinner. Thank you, hope I can find how to fix the cursor thing.

Comment: @Josef That's actually a rather creative solution! As for the cursor thing, I think you can fix it with a position:fixed, but I am not sure how the code works. Best of luck!

Comment: @gengkev What do you mean with that? Where should I put tha property?

Comment: Position: fixed to what? And thank you :-)

Comment: @Josef try putting it on the canvas's `style` attribute, replacing the `position: absolute` that's already there; it will change the effect but i think that might be how the code was designed to work